# $\mathbb{R}$ as $\limsup$ of sets of Lebesgue measure $1$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm working through F. Jones' book "Lebesgue integration on Euclidean space" on my own. This question is part of problem 7 in chapter 6.

Part of the problem requires one to show that there exists a sequence of measurable sets $A_k\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, all having measure $1$ and such that $\limsup A_k =\mathbb{R}$.

I've tried everything I can think of to construct such a sequence. I'm having trouble thinking of sets having measure $1$ that can accomplish this. Since the limsup is the set of those points which are on infinitely many $A_k$, I'm having trouble shaking off the feeling that measure $1$ sets are "too small" to do this.

Cold you help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: you can accomplish this where each $A_k$ is an interval of length $1$...!

Remember that the lim sup of a sequence of sets is the set of points that are in infinitely many of the sets in the sequence. By way of analogy, what is the lim sup of the sequence of sets $$\{1\},\{2\},\{1\},\{3\},\{2\},\{1\},\{4\},\{3\},\{2\},\{1\},\{5\},\{4\},\{3\},\{2\},\{1\},\dots?$$

Comment: Thanks for the useful hint! Maybe I'm mistaken, my understanding of the limsup is not so good yet I think. In this case, I think the limsup is the set of all natural numbers right? If this is correct, then I think I understand the suggestion! I could put intervals next to each other and "repeat" them as in this sequence right? (this is genius!)